# frequencies of dice rolls, then getting most occurring roll

Tags: python

so, i wrote this code which first makes a list of 1000 rolls. then i wrote a function which uses dictionaries to have the frequency of every die roll. then i want to print the roll which occurred the most, and its frequency.

```
import random
L = []
for i in range(1000):
    currentRoll = random.randint(1, 6)
    L.append(currentRoll)


def diceFreq(L):
    rollCount = {}
    for roll in L:
        if roll not in rollCount:
            rollCount[roll] = 1
        else:
            rollCount[roll] += 1
    print(rollCount)
    print(max(rollCount, key=rollCount.get))
    print(max(rollCount.values()))

diceFreq(L)
```

i dont understand what exactly `print(max(rollCount, key=rollCount.get))` doing in words?

Comment: `key` takes a function reference. Not a called function, a reference to a function that it can call at the time of sorting. So, each item encountered during `max()` doing its work, `rollCount` can be called to see how many times that `roll` occurred (by calling `get` on your counter dictionary for that particular value)

Comment: Just a general suggestion: You should look into Counter. It does what your diceFreq function does for you and theoretically faster than looping through your list.. Link: https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html

Answer (score 2):

Max will receive an iterable and evaluate the max value.
I.e:

```
max([1,2,3]) # >> returns 3
max("abc") # >> returns 'c'
max({"a": 10, "b": 5}) # >> returns 'b'
```

Your `rollCount` is a dict that will iterate through keys by default.

However, when you add a `key` to the max function, it will evaluate the value to be considered `max` against the callable you set.

I.e:

```
max([1,2,3], key=lambda x: -x) # >> returns 1
```

In this case, it will compare the maximum value after sending it to the callable.
(1,2,3 would became -1,-2,-3 for the comparison, but will return the original value).

When you call `.get` from a dict, it will expect a `key` to be passed. when you do this:

```
d = {"a": 10, "b": 5}
max(d, key=d.get)  # returns 'a'
```

Instead of comparing `'a' >= 'b'` it will do `d.get('a') >= d.get('b')`.

```
d.get('a') # >> 10
d.get('b') # >> 5
```

Returning in this case `'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you take advantage of the [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class, which does all the work of your `diceFreq` function in a much more Pythonic manner. It will

- Count the number of occurrences of each roll
- Sort the rolls from most occurring to least occurring
- Return a dictionary of roll:count key-value pairs.

So you can replace the entire `diceFreq()` defintion with this:

```py
import collections
import operator
print(collections.Counter(L).most_common(1)[0])
```

Line 3 creates such a Counter from L. You can print this out to verify it has six items, one for each roll. Each item in the dictionary has an associated count, all adding up to 1000. Then it uses the `most_common(1)` method to only return the most frequently rolled value and its count. Finally we use the slice `[0]` to get the tuple out of the list that `most_common()` returned.

Comment: I agree that there are better ways of doing it but the question was `i dont understand what exactly print(max(rollCount, key=rollCount.get)) doing in words? `.

Comment: If you're going to use a `Counter`, then you might as well use the `most_common` method since it's more convenient than `max`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common

Comment: Good point @kaya3 -- forgot about that really useful method. I'm so used to seeing dictionaries without that specialized operation, that when I want to sort them, I just use `sorted()` and a lambda with `itemgetter()` out of reflex. Updated my answer.